# Вставить элемент в сторонний компонент

Tags: reactjs

Я использую сторонний компонент "слайдер" ([rc-slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-slider)). Мне нужно добавить дополнительный элемент внутрь бегунка слайдера (`div class="rc-slider-handle"`).

Comment: а <Handle value={value} {...restProps} >ваш код</Handle> пробовали?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov там нужно не в родительский вставить, а внутрь бегунка, т.е. есть еще вложенность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно передавать именно React компонент, потому что с простыми HTML тегами не работает.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Slider, { Range } from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';

class MyAwesomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>CUSTOM HANDLER</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <Slider
      handle={ (handleProps) => {
        return (
          <Slider.Handle { ...handleProps }>
              <MyAwesomeComponent />
          </Slider.Handle>
        )
      }}
    />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[Источник](https://github.com/react-component/slider/issues/449)